# Magento rewrite product url to link with categories

Tags: magento-1, url-rewrite

Version : Magento 1.18

Our actual URLs for the same product :

```
store.com/product-name-1.html

store.com/cat1/cat2/product-name-1.html
```

How we can redirect the first URL to the second URL

> store.com/product-name-1.html == **Redirect to** ==>
>   store.com/cat1/cat2/product-name-1.html

Answer (score 0):

From [Vinoth's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16832/5443) on [Include categories in product URL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5083/include-categories-in-product-url)

- From the Admin menu, select System > Configuration.
- In the Configuration panel on the left, select Catalog. Click to
  expand the Search Engine Optimizations section. Then, do the
  following:

  - To remove the suffix from product URLs, clear the default “.html”
    setting from the Product URL Suffix field.
  - To remove the suffix from category URLs, clear the default “.html”
    setting from the Category URL Suffix field.

  Note: For an existing catalog, you will need to refresh the Search
     Indexing (Catalog > Search Indexing) and browser cache (F5).

  - To omit the category path from product URLs, set Use Categories Path
    for Product URLs to “No.”
- When complete, click the Save Config button.